# How to create circular horizontal roller with item selected

Tags: android, listview, uiscrollview

I have to create a circular year roller in one of my app. Below is my requirement as an image. Please have a look in it.

[image]

Years may be vary according to requirement like Year1, Year2,... Yearn. This roller should scroll horizontal in both the directions. When user select a particular year, that year should be selected in middle with bold font and corresponding data shown below as a list view. There should be only three years at a time in a row as shown in below image.

I have follow the below links but didn't meet my requirement. Please suggest me a relevant solution to achieve the same task.

[Closed or circular Horizontal ListView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211638/closed-or-circular-horizontal-listview-android)

[create Circular Horizontal ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220259/how-to-create-circular-horizontal-scrollview)

Thanks for your giving time :)

I need just as it is as IOS [IOS circular roller](https://github.com/valitovaza/scrollableTabbar)

Comment: try this library. hope its helps to you. https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But the tabs are not circular. I need circular tabs means reaping tabs. Can you please help me to achieve the same ?